# How to create combinations of inner array elements inside a main n-length array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the result I'm looking for:

```
Input : [ 
            [
                {a: [v]}, 
                {b: [v]}
            ],
            [
                {c: [v]},
                {d: [v]}
            ]
        ]

Output : [
            {
                a: [v],
                c: [v]
            },
            {
                a: [v],
                d: [v]
            },
            {
                b: [v],
                c: [v]
            },
            {
                b: [v],
                d: [v]
            }
         ]
```

First it is an array of arrays made with objects. Then it turns to an array of objects. Each combination can have one element of each original array only. My attempt is the following:

```
  arr.forEach((d, i) => {
    d.forEach((l, j) => {
      temp[j] ? temp[j].push(l) : temp[j] = [l];
    });
  });
```

But I haven't figured out yet how to do it.

Comment: Will every array entry object contain exactly two inner arrays, no more and no less? Or can there be an arbitrary number of inner arrays?

Comment: There can be an arbitrary number of inner arrays @IceMetalPunk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript)